# How can I see the entire output of a python file when run inside terminal?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, iterm2

Terminal automatically cut the output as it scrolled up with each iteration.

Comment: If you're running a script with that much output, you're better off redirecting it to a file anyway.

Comment: `python3 myscript.py | less`

Comment: The python program I am running is particularly resource expensive, and therefore, I really don't want to run it again. Is there a way to store the output of the previously run command in a text file?

Comment: @adityak42: No.

Answer (score 0):

By default mac terminal will have a limited no of lines of buffer. Say 1,000.

When you run a program and the output crossed 1000 lines your lines will be lost from memory. It's like FIFO buffer queue.

Basically the answer to your question:

```
`Is there a way to store the output of the previously run command in a text file?` is no. Sorry.
```

You can re-run the program and preserve the output by redirecting it to another file. Or increase the number of lines in the buffer (Maybe make it unlimited)

You can use less to go through the output:

```
your_command | less
```

Your `Enter` key will take you down.

Also, press `q` to exit.

**Or** you can reroute the output to a file

In one terminal tab run the program and redirect the output to a `output.log` file like this.

```
python program.py > output.log
```

In another tab you can `tailf` on the same log file and see the output.

```
tailf output.log
```

To see the complete output open the log file in any text editor.

You can consider increasing the scrollback buffer.

[image]

**Or**

If you want to see the data and also run it to a file, use tee, e.g,

spark-shell | tee tmp.out

Comment: The python program I am running is particularly resource expensive, and therefore, I really don't want to run it again. Is there a way to store the output of the previously run command in a text file?

Comment: @adityak42 Did you downvote? Because you didn't mention this in the original question `The python program I am running is particularly resource expensive, and therefore, I really don't want to run it again. Is there a way to store the output of the previously run command in a text file?`. Anyways check my answer. I don't think you can recover what is already gone from your buffer. It's simply not there in the memory anymore. So probably you will have to re-run the program.